# Finite Coins - using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Given 1 coin from multiple denominations (E.G. a 1 coin, 5 coin, 16 coin), and a sum, return true or false determining if the sum can be made.

```
boolean go(int[] coins, int goal) 
{
  //Will set each time, but shouldn't matter as toggle is at bottom
  boolean ans = false;
   
  //loop running in recursion till founds ans
   
  //Really bad time complexity lol
  for (int i = 0; i < coins.length && (!ans); i++) {
    if ((goal - coins[i] == 0) || goal == 0) {
      return true;
    }
     
    if (goal > coins[i]) {
      int[] red = new int[coins.length - 1];
      //it necessary because making list with one less
      int it = 0;
      //Setting new list to avoid runtime
      for(int x = 0; x < coins.length; x++){
        if(!(i == x)){
          red[it] = coins[i];
          it += 1;
        }
      }
      //Run with new list
      ans = go(red, goal - coins[i]);
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

This is my code so far. I have made it recursive, yet one of the test cases returns true when it should not. The test case in particular is [111, 1, 2, 3, 9, 11, 20, 30], with the goal doing 8; This should return false (as it cannot add up to 8), but in this case, returns true.

Other test cases work fine, so I believe my code has some sort of an exception.

I have tried to move the base case upward, and make a reverse variation...

```
boolean go(int[] coins, int goal) 
{
  boolean ans = false;
  if(goal == 0){
    return true;
  }else if(goal < 0){
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < coins.length && (!ans); i++) {
    if (goal >= coins[i]) {
      int[] red = new int[coins.length - 1];
      int it = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x < coins.length; x++){
        if(!(i == x)){
          red[it] = coins[i];
          it += 1;
        }
      }
      ans = go(red, goal - coins[i]);
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

is what I've tried, but the base case doesn't seem to affect anything

Comment: Might be missing just the base case, google recursion base case to see if that helps

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear. The way I read it, you are given [1, 5, 16] and a sum of 22 and the answer would be yes that you can make the sum of 22 given the three coins. It looks like a simple iteration and sum. What are the actual requirements?

Comment: For example, if you are given [1, 5 ,16], you could definitely get 22, right? What if you were give [12,4,120,240,32] and asked if you could get 36? You would need to return true. If you were given, for example, [1,2, 5, 60,12, 452] and asked if you could get 4, you would have to return false; Iteration would just add these sums together
@JaredRenzullo

Comment: @terpinmd I looked into it, but wouldn't the return inside the for statement serve to be a base case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is in your copying of the coins array: `red[it] = coins[i]` should really be `red[it] = coins[x]`...

For time complexity, you don't really have to do a loop inside the method. Each denomination is either part of the sum or not, so you can always remove the first denomination and test with and without it:

```
boolean go(int[] coins, int goal)  {
    if(goal == 0)
        return true;
    else if(coins.length == 0 || goal < 0)
        return false;
    else {
        int[] tailOfCoins = Arrays.copyOfRange(coins, 1, coins.length);
        return go(tailOfCoins, goal) || go(tailOfCoins, goal - coins[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand most of what you did, just by checking the first denomination each time. The time-complexity solution you mentioned is so much more cleaner than my code haha

Comment: ... and if the problem changes to infinite coins of each denomination, you will probably need to revert to that Dynamic programming to get it performant... Good luck!